# ¿Cómo junto todas las líneas en una sola?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#!/bin/bash

FSTAB=` grep -v "^#" /etc/fstab | grep . | grep -v "swap" | grep -v "UUID"   | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'`

for i in $FSTAB
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

esto me devuelve:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root
/
xfs
/dev/sdb2
/hdos
xfs
```

El problema es que más adelante lo quiero comparar, entonces me lo está devolviendo con saltos de linea y quiero que me lo devuelva en una sola linea sin saltos es decir asi:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root / xfs /dev/sdb2 /hdos xfs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que estás usando `awk`, puedes dejar que lo haga el mismo, evitando que añada un salto de línea al final de cada una. Cambia

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
```

por

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3}'
```

Y, siguiendo con `awk`, puedes simplificar **todas** esa interconexiones de comandos:

```
FSTAB=`awk '/^#/{next} /swap/{next } /UUID/{next} {printf "%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3}'`
```

La síntaxis `/EXPRESION-REGULAR/{ ... }` ejecuta el código **solo** si la expresión regular coincide, mientras que `{next}` descarta la línea actual para continuar con la siguiente.

Comment: también puedes decir `awk '/^#/ || /swap/ || /UUID/ {next}'`. Es decir, puedes anidar las condiciones que hacen saltar a la siguiente línea. O directamente decir `awk '!(/^#/ || /swap/ || /UUID/) {printf ...}'`.

Answer (score 2):

Si el resultado que te devuelve un simple `echo "$FSTAB"` es

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root
/
xfs
/dev/sdb2
/hdos
xfs
```

Entonces puedes eliminar o reemplazar los saltos de línea "\n" con `tr`.

```
$ echo "$FSTAB" | tr '\n' ' '
```

O con `sed`

```
$ echo "$FSTAB" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

La explicación (que no la sé) la puedes encontrar de otra [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed).

En ambos casos, el bucle `for` es innecesario.

Y ya todos andamos en el tren de `awk`, una opción que creo viable, es la de:

```
$ egrep -v "^#|(swap|UUID)" fstab | awk '{for (i=1; i<=3; i++){printf $i" "}}'
/dev/sda1 / ext4 /dev/sda3 /home ext4 LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / ext3 /dev/mapper/centos-root / xfs
```

De un archivo de la forma.

```
# <device>        <dir>        <type>        <options>        <dump> <fsck>
/dev/sda1         /            ext4          noatime          0      1
/dev/sda2         none         swap          defaults         0      0
/dev/sda3         /home        ext4          noatime          0      2
UUID=881350dc-1eef-47b4-bec4-199454179b4e / ext3 defaults 1 1
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / ext3 defaults 1 1
/dev/mapper/centos-root / xfs defaults 1 1
```

O recorriendo el array de campos.

```
$ egrep -v "^#|(swap|UUID)" fstab | awk '{NF-=3; printf "%s " ,$0}'
```

O además, siguiendo el consejo de `next`.

```
$ awk '/^#|(swap|UUID)/{ next; }{NF-=3; printf "%s " ,$0}' fstab
```

O mejor negando la regex.

```
$ awk '!/^#|(swap|UUID)/{NF-=3; printf "%s " ,$0}' fstab
```

Lo cual también lo puedes resolver con `cut`y `xargs`.

```
$ egrep -v "^#|(swap|UUID)" fstab | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 1-3 | xargs
```